# PHP SOAP response

Tags: php, html, xml, soap

I am using the PHP specific `SOAPClient` in order to call for a soap API and get responses.
The problem I have is that I do not manage to get in order the results, neither to extract them.

The code I am using is:

```
<?php

$wsdl = 'http://portalquery.just.ro/Query.asmx?wsdl';
$client = new SoapClient($wsdl);

$xml_array['numarDosar'] = '10080/3/2013';
$response = $client->CautareDosare2($xml_array);


var_dump($response);

?>
```

The results I get are:

```
object(stdClass)#2 (1) { ["CautareDosare2Result"]=> object(stdClass)#3 (1) { ["Dosar"]=> array(2) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#4 (13) { ["parti"]=> object(stdClass)#5 (1) { ["DosarParte"]=> array(3) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#6 (2) { ["nume"]=> string(22) "Mocanu Andrei Cristian" ["calitateParte"]=> string(17) "Recurent Inculpat" } [1]=> object(stdClass)#7 (2) { ["nume"]=> string(21) "Mocanu Răzvan George" ["calitateParte"]=> string(17) "Recurent Inculpat" } [2]=> object(stdClass)#8 (2) { ["nume"]=> string(11) "Mica Marian" ["calitateParte"]=> string(17) "Recurent Inculpat" } } } ["sedinte"]=> object(stdClass)#9 (1) { ["DosarSedinta"]=> object(stdClass)#10 (9) { ["complet"]=> string(26) "S2 Complet urgentă recurs" ["data"]=> string(19) "2013-03-14T00:00:00" ["ora"]=> string(5) "12:00" ["solutie"]=> string(14) "Respins recurs" ["solutieSumar"]=> string(408) "Înc. 82/R/În majoritate :Respinge ca nefondate recursurile declararate de recurenţii inculpaţi Mocanu Andrei Cristian, Mocanu Răzvan George şi Mica Marian. Obligă pe fiecare recurent la câte 300 lei cheltuieli judiciare către stat. Pronunţată în şedinţă publică, azi, 14.03.2013. Opinie separată în sensul admiterii recursurilor şi luării măsurii obligării de a nu părăsi localitatea." ["dataPronuntare"]=> string(19) "2013-03-14T00:00:00" ["documentSedinta"]=> string(33) "incheieremasuripreventivefazadeUP" ["numarDocument"]=> string(7) "82/2013" ["dataDocument"]=> string(19) "2013-03-14T00:00:00" } } ["numar"]=> string(12) "10080/3/2013" ["numarVechi"]=> string(8) "831/2013" ["data"]=> string(19) "2013-03-14T00:00:00" ["institutie"]=> string(21) "CurteadeApelBUCURESTI" ["departament"]=> string(22) "Secţia a II-a penală" ["categorieCaz"]=> string(5) "Penal" ["stadiuProcesual"]=> string(6) "Recurs" ["obiect"]=> string(113) "prelungirea duratei arestării preventive dispuse în cursul urmăririi penale (art. 156 şi următoarele C.p.p.)" ["dataModificare"]=> string(23) "2017-01-18T06:48:34.467" ["categorieCazNume"]=> string(5) "Penal" ["stadiuProcesualNume"]=> string(6) "Recurs" } [1]=> object(stdClass)#11 (14) { ["parti"]=> object(stdClass)#12 (1) { ["DosarParte"]=> array(3) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#13 (2) { ["nume"]=> string(22) "MOCANU ANDREI CRISTIAN" ["calitateParte"]=> string(8) "Inculpat" } [1]=> object(stdClass)#14 (2) { ["nume"]=> string(20) "MOCANU RAZVAN GEORGE" ["calitateParte"]=> string(8) "Inculpat" } [2]=> object(stdClass)#15 (2) { ["nume"]=> string(11) "MICA MARIAN" ["calitateParte"]=> string(8) "Inculpat" } } } ["sedinte"]=> object(stdClass)#16 (1) { ["DosarSedinta"]=> object(stdClass)#17 (9) { ["complet"]=> string(5) "CC1 -" ["data"]=> string(19) "2013-03-12T00:00:00" ["ora"]=> string(5) "23:59" ["solutie"]=> string(12) "Soluţionare" ["solutieSumar"]=> string(311) "În baza prevederilor art. 155 şi urm. C.p.p. dispune prelungirea măsurii arestării preventive a inculpaţilor Mocanu Andrei Cristian, Mocanu Răzvan George şi Mica Marius pe o perioadă de 20 de zile, de la 15.03.2013 - 03.04.2013, inclusiv. Cu recurs. Pronunţată în şedinţă publică azi, 12.03.2013." ["dataPronuntare"]=> string(19) "2013-03-12T00:00:00" ["documentSedinta"]=> string(27) "incheierefinaladezinvestire" ["numarDocument"]=> string(0) "" ["dataDocument"]=> string(19) "2013-03-12T00:00:00" } } ["caiAtac"]=> object(stdClass)#18 (1) { ["DosarCaleAtac"]=> object(stdClass)#19 (3) { ["dataDeclarare"]=> string(19) "2013-03-13T00:00:00" ["parteDeclaratoare"]=> string(37) " MICA MARIAN, MOCANU RAZVAN GEORGE, " ["tipCaleAtac"]=> string(6) "Recurs" } } ["numar"]=> string(12) "10080/3/2013" ["numarVechi"]=> string(0) "" ["data"]=> string(19) "2013-03-11T00:00:00" ["institutie"]=> string(19) "TribunalulBUCURESTI" ["departament"]=> string(22) "Secţia a-II-a Penală" ["categorieCaz"]=> string(5) "Penal" ["stadiuProcesual"]=> string(4) "Fond" ["obiect"]=> string(113) "prelungirea duratei arestării preventive dispuse în cursul urmăririi penale (art. 156 şi următoarele C.p.p.)" ["dataModificare"]=> string(23) "2017-01-18T08:33:50.877" ["categorieCazNume"]=> string(5) "Penal" ["stadiuProcesualNume"]=> string(4) "Fond" } } } }
```

I tried to explode on the results, also used $response[1]->array and such, nothing works.

Comment: can you share `print_r($response);`?

Comment: Is that not an Object?

Comment: Please ensure what is your requirement from above `$response`

Comment: @SahilGulati if I am trying to print it, it will return Parse error: parse error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in C:\appserv\soap.php on line 22

Comment: @PHPglue I am new to PHP, it might be possible to be an object, I do not really know :<

Comment: @SahilGulati my requirements are that I would like to extract all objects and arrays in the response, like: Dosar: 10080/3/2013, Parte: Mocanu Andrei Cristian (Recurent-Inculpat) etc... I do not know how to extract the objects, and the arrays, so I could manipulate them as I need

Comment: Also the variables

Comment: @AndrewStephen Please check my post and let me know if something else is required

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
$wsdl = 'http://portalquery.just.ro/Query.asmx?wsdl';
$client = new SoapClient($wsdl);

$xml_array['numarDosar'] = '10080/3/2013';
$response = $client->CautareDosare2($xml_array);
$resultArray=  json_decode(json_encode($response),true);
$arrayOnfirstKey=$resultArray[key($resultArray)];
$arrayOnSecondKey=  $arrayOnfirstKey[key($arrayOnfirstKey)];
echo "<table>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>nume</td>";
echo "<td>CalitateParte</td>";
echo "</tr>";
foreach($arrayOnSecondKey as $value)
{
    foreach($value["parti"]["DosarParte"] as $data)
    {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" .$data["nume"]."</td>";
        echo "<td>" .$data["calitateParte"]."</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
}
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: Warning: json_encode() expects exactly 1 parameter, 2 given in C:\appserv\soap2.php on line 7

Warning: key() [function.key]: Passed variable is not an array or object in C:\appserv\soap2.php on line 8

Warning: key() [function.key]: Passed variable is not an array or object in C:\appserv\soap2.php on line 9

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\appserv\soap2.php on line 10

Comment: @AndrewStephen Working on that, and giving you expected result

Comment: @AndrewStephen above is working fine for me, can you please check again

Comment: Hello, Now it seems to be working, I am receiving the following: Array ( [parti] => Array ( [DosarParte] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [nume] => Mocanu Andrei Cristian [calitateParte] => Recurent Inculpat ) [1] => Array ( [nume] => Mocanu Răzvan George [calitateParte] => Recurent Inculpat ) [2] => Array ( [nume] => Mica Marian [calitateParte] => Recurent Inculpat ) ) ) --- Is it possible to return each of the object -> array -> variable?

Comment: yes, so my question is, Do you want to extract some information from resultant array

Comment: Yes, I would like to extract them to be shown as on http://portal.just.ro/2/SitePages/Dosar.aspx?id_dosar=200000000301420&id_inst=2

Comment: @AndrewStephen You can check now

Comment: Yes, it works. Thank you. Is it possible that I could make them look like on the webpage? it seems that the data retrieved is very hard to handle.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you! now I'm trying to extend its functionality to the other objects and arrays!

Comment: @AndrewStephen welcome ...:) Hope you will accept my answer

Comment: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\appserv\soap3.php on line 34, if I'm trying to read more than foreach($value["parti"]["DosarParte"] as $data)